# Additional newline is not appearing after input Python

Tags: python, input, newline

This is the desired output.

```
Number of Econ motorcycle: 2
Number of Standard motorcycle: 1
Number of Premium motorcycle: 1
Rental duration (number of days): 4
# I want a newline here

Summary of your car rental for 4 day(s)
Economy      2  $320.00
Standard     1  $280.00
Premium      1  $400.00
SUV          0  $0.00
Subtotal     4  $1000.00
Total (18% tax) $1180.00
```

I have tried:
print()
print(chr(10)
""" """ - multiline string
\n

All of this doesn't seem to work.

```
def get_car_rental_booking():
    # Prompt user number of cars for each type and rental duration
    noOfeconomy = int(input("Number of Economy motorcycle: "))
    noOfstandard = int(input("Number of Standards motorcycle: "))
    noOfpremium = int(input("Number of Premium motorcycle: "))
    print("Rental duration (number of days): ", end="")
    rentalDuration = int(input("Rental duration (number of days): "))

 
    print(chr(10))
    # Compute the cost for each motorcycle type
    costEconomy = noOfeconomy * 40 * rentalDuration
    costStandard = noOfstandard * 70 * rentalDuration
    costPremium = noOfpremium * 100 * rentalDuration

    # Compute the total cost including tax 
    subTotal = costEconomy + costStandard + costPremium + costSuv
    total = subTotal * 1.18

    # There is an empty line after getting the inputs.
    dollarSign = "$"
    newLine = "\n"
    print(f'\n\n{newLine}Summary of your motorcycle rental for {rentalDuration} day(s)')
    costEconomy_string = dollarSign + format(costEconomy, '.2f')
    print(f"{'Economy':<13} {noOfeconomy:^3} {costEconomy_string:>10}")
    costStandard_string = dollarSign + format(costStandard, '.2f')
    print(f"{'Standard':<13} {noOfstandard:^3} {costStandard_string:>10}")
    costPremium_string = dollarSign + format(costPremium, '.2f')
    print(f"{'Premium':<13} {noOfpremium:^3} {costPremium_string:>10}")
    costSubtotal_string = dollarSign + format(subTotal, '.2f')
    print(f"{'Subtotal':<13} {rentalDuration:^3} {costSubtotal_string:>10}")
    costTotal_string = dollarSign + format(total, '.2f')
    print(f"{'Total (18% tax)':16}  {costTotal_string:>10}")
```

I have tried:
print()
print(chr(10)
""" """ - multiline string
\n

I was expecting a gap right after the input and before the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have some spacing and delineation formatting such as:

`f"{'Premium':<13} {noOfpremium:^3} {costPremium_string:>10}"`

But maybe you could clean up and adapt a `string.Template` to do most of the printing for you. At the very least, it helps abstract your computation logic from the printout / summary.

Try extending this simplified example to your needs:

```
from string import Template

tmp = Template('''
Number of Economy cars: $economy_cars_count
Number of Standard cars: $standard_cars_count
Number of Premium cars: $premium_cars_count
Number of SUVs: $suv_cars_count
Rental duration (number of days): $rental_duration_days

Summary of your car rental for 4 day(s)
Economy      $economy_cars_count  $$$economy_cars_rental_cost
Standard     $standard_cars_count  $$$standard_cars_rental_cost
Premium      $premium_cars_count $$$premium_cars_rental_cost
SUV          $suv_cars_count  $$$suv_cars_rental_cost
Subtotal     4  $$$subtotal
Total ($tax_percentage% tax) $$$total
''')

s = tmp.substitute(dict(
    economy_cars_count=1,
    standard_cars_count=2,
    premium_cars_count=3,
    suv_cars_count=4,
    rental_duration_days=4,
    economy_cars_rental_cost=10,
    standard_cars_rental_cost=20,
    premium_cars_rental_cost=30,
    suv_cars_rental_cost=40,
    subtotal=500,
    tax_percentage=18,
    total=590
))
print(s)
```

```
Number of Economy cars: 1
Number of Standard cars: 2
Number of Premium cars: 3
Number of SUVs: 4
Rental duration (number of days): 4

Summary of your car rental for 4 day(s)
Economy      2  $10
Standard     1  $20
Premium      1  $30
SUV          0  $40
Subtotal     4  $500
Total (18% tax) $590
```

check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings

Comment: interesting, thanks for suggesting it. I will try but I don't think this is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a newline after the user finishes typing his input, by adding:

`print("\n")`

after the user submits his input.

Using `\n` in a string created a new line.

Comment: Note that you can't use "smart" or curly quotes in python. Your code throws `SyntaxError: invalid character '“'`. Please edit to show simple quotes instead (`"` instead of `”`)

Comment: Sorry about that, I was on my phone typing the quotes.

I have updated the answer to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks for suggesting, but I have tried this, and it doesn't work.

refer to screenshot: 
https://ibb.co/dkG2zvx

Answer (score 0):

I used an online Python interpreter to interpret my code, but it did not give my desired output. However, it works well on VScode.

So the platform you run your code on matters.